# how to make a jquery click event happen more than once

Tags: jquery, click

disclaimer one: i am brand spanking new to jquery, and this my first post to SO.

disclaimer two: i have searched my question many different ways, and HAVE FOUND many detailed answers, and yet i still cannot get my jquery to work as i would like it to.

that said:

i am trying to create a mobile version of my website.
(for reference, the desktop & tablet version is here: http://creative-servic.es)

what i need for the mobile version, is for the main portfolio images and the thumbnail gallery to switch places when the gallery-icon in the footer is clicked, and then when a thumb is clicked, they switch back again, and the portfolio image whose thumbnail was clicked is now visible at the top of the page. which all works (yay!)... but only once :(

in other words, once a thumbnail is selected, i can no longer get the gallery to activate via its icon in the footer.

i know this is a rather common problem, and has something to do with something no longer existing in the DOM after the event is requested. but please go easy on me with the lingo -- i am not even really sure what a DOM is in the first place, nor what binding is (or unbinding) for that matter, but these are some of the somewhat confusing terms that keep coming up in my research.

here is the mobile mockup in question: http://mnml.cc/ces/m

i have tried the .live, .on, .click, and .delegate functions to no avail.

any assistance in this matter would be greatly greatly appreciated!

many thanks and
warmest regards, Dd.

Comment: The console shows a javascript error - the function `gallery()` (see the code for the gallery button) is not found.  Where is it?

Comment: hi sideroxylon. it is in functions.js the code is//GALLERY
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#gallery-icon').click(function() {
  var toggleWidth = $('#gallery').width() === 0 ? "100%" : "0";
  $('#gallery').animate({
   width: toggleWidth
  });
  $(this).toggleClass('on');
 });
 $("#gallery a").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
 });
});

Comment: Yes, saw that - that's a click function bound to the element `gallery-icon', not a function called gallery().  Check your console when you click on the icon.

Comment: you are so right. see? i am such a beginner, that i really had no idea how to properly create a js link. what i just did to get rid of the console errors was to put those icons in a <button> tag. now i have no more console errors (i think). i also changed the .click to .on in the functions.js -- but i still cannot get it to work. any further thoughts on this?

Comment: i also tried it as an anonymous function. it also got rid of the console errors, but it also didn't work. do i need to actually create something called "gallery()"?? if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page works now unless you click on one of the thumbnail images (after first clicking on the gallery icon).  The reason looks like this:  when your page loads, the div `gallery' has a width of 0, but has height and opacity. Then, in your click function you have:

```
$("#gallery a").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

This hides the `gallery` div (by reducing width, height and opacity to 0 = display:none - check the console and you'll see this happen).  Finally, the click function bound to `#gallery-icon` only toggles the div width - it doesn't change the 0 height and 0 opacity.  Try changing the above code to something like:

```
$("#gallery a").on('click', function() {
    $('#gallery').css('width', 0);
});
```

This should set it to its original state, and the `gallery-icon' click function should then be able to toggle the width of a visible div.

(You can animate the function as well, if you wish, to reverse the original click function.)

Comment: worked like a charm. you are my hero - many thanks for your help!

Comment: hi again, sideroxylon.

Comment: i am trying different things with the mobile version, and i have run across a similar problem as before. i have changed the animation effect from toggleWidth to push-sliding left/right. the new problem is two fold. problem one is that i can only use the gallery icon in the footer to open the gallery, but i can no longer toggle it closed from the footer -- first a thumbnail needs to be selected and the gallery closed again, in order to be able to use the button again.

Comment: and problem two is that when the main images are visible, i can horizontally scroll over to the gallery. this is unwanted behavior. i should not be seeing the gallery unless its icon in the footer is clicked. i tried to mess with the overflow-x properties on numerous divs, but to no avail. oddly though, when the gallery is open i do not have the same problem.

Comment: when the gallery is open there is no scrollable overflow in the x-direction (which is good, i just need it for the portfolio too). i can imagine that this (a sort of double-wide site right now) is also causing me footer problems, because i cannot see the footer on a phone. hopefully if the x-overflow gets resolved, then the footer will correct itself? this new version is here: http://mnml.cc/ces/m2. any further assistance would be greatly greatly appreciated. -Dd.

Comment: The reason you can't toggle it closed from the footer is that you don't have a toggle function bound to the button.  When the gallery is displayed, it's already where it should be at the end of the animation, so nothing happens.  You're probably better off just animating the width of the portfolio: '$('#portfolio').animate({width: 'toggle'});`.  You could even do both at once '$('#portfolio, #gallery').animate({width: 'toggle'});` (assuming the gallery starts with `width:0` and portfolio with `width:100%`).  This would solve the horizontal scroll issue at the same time.

Comment: thank you again, and yes - of course. i saw that .toggle has been removed from jquery, but i found a script that replicates it called ".toggleClick", so i used that to animate my left/right sliding divs. i also fixed the overflow issue by setting the wrapper div to overflow:hidden and the two inner divs to position:relative. now it ALMOST works perfectly, except that now once i activate a big image by clicking its thumbnail, i have to hit the gallery icon twice to get it to toggle properly again. any idea why? and if so, how do i eliminate the need for the extra click?

Comment: The reason you have to click the icon twice is that your toggle and selection functions are separate - the toggle function doesn't know that the selection function has already reversed the initial animation - and so it tries to do it again.  You could try something like: $('#gallery a').click(function() {$('#gallery-icon').trigger('click');}).  That uses the click on a large image to trigger the second click on the icon, so that the toggle is back in sequence.

Comment: absolutely perfect! you have been so informative and helpful - i cannot thank you enough. one last issue, i promise! is there an easy way to disable the project-info link in the footer (the one with the 3 horizontal lines) while the gallery is open? it seems counter intuitive to me that that link is still active while the thumbnails are visible, yet when they are, clicking that link does nothing. it opens/closes the info, but it happens offscreen, and as such is rather pointless. so i would love to disable that link when the gallery is visible...

Comment: ...and at the same time, move its background-position in the y-direction by 96px so that it appears greyed-out (grey is my indicator that an icon is "on hold", and temporarily non-functional). is that relatively easy to do, or do i need to start creating active-states, and holding-states for things? thank you again. your most recent solution (that clicking on one thing simulates a click on another) was also employed to closing the submenu when clicking on the submenu link of the current page. totally awesome!

Comment: also, are you for hire? i am not a programmer. i am just a designer who likes to make useable mockups (and learn while doing so). if you are for hire i have immediate need for the programming of a music mixing website, and i always have a couple of projects going on. if you want to talk business let me know and we can connect by email. thanks again, David.

Comment: I'd suggest you create a 'disabled' class for the button, and toggle it at the same time as you toggle the class of the gallery button.  To make it unclickable, just include `pointer-events: none;` in the class.  At the same time you can use a grayscale filter on the project icon - or easiest of all, just hide the icon while the thumbnails are displayed..

Comment: that works perfectly, but only when the project-info is hidden. and i fully understand why - it is because clicking the project-info changes its class, and then clicking the gallery icon resets the project-info's class to its default class. but i don't always want its default class to be active. is there a js function not to simply toggle its default class, but to only toggle its immediately preceding class? does that make any sense? click-on the project info, and then use the gallery, and you will see what i mean.

Comment: OK, I see the issue.  Toggles are never fun.  The problem is that your `.hold` class sets a new background position, and when you remove the class, the element reverts to the original CSS.  Maybe try closing the project-info when the gallery is opened?  Add something like `$('.project-info').slideUp('fast');` to the first function in Gallery Toggle.  Then, when the gallery is opened, the project info should be hidden and the icon will be in the correct state when a gallery image is clicked and the portfolio images are visible again.

Comment: that is better than before - thank you. but not exactly what i need. what that does is close the project-info if it is open before the gallery activation. the problem is, if the project-info was open before the gallery activation, i need it to still be there when the gallery closes. i don't want to see it opening or closing, it just needs to stay on or off, before and after the gallery activation.

Comment: can some sort of conditional statement be added to the javascript? something based on the background position of the icon: IF position 0 THEN return to position 0 ELSE return to position 1? or based on the div's visibility? maybe?

Comment: Remove the `slideUp` function from the first part of the gallery toggle, and change `toggleClass('hold')` to `addClass('hold').  Then in the second part, replace `toggleClass` on `project-info` with something like: `if(!$('.project-info').is(':visible')){'.project-info').removeClass('hold');} else { $('.project-info').addClass('on')}`  This should check to see if the overlay is displayed (`block`) - if so, when closing the gallery, the `project-info` button will be given the '`on'` class (which should over-write the `background-position`setting).  If not, it will be returned to the default.

Comment: that was close and partially right, but still had some weird behavior. it didn't need a conditional statement after all. check it out now to see what worked. oh (!) there is no longer a mobile only version. i just made one master website with a slightly different stylesheet for tablets, and another for phones. the mockup is now here - http://mnml.cc/ces. probably best to view on a desktop, because on non-mouse devices there is still some "sticky" hover issues, which will get resolved on the real site.

Comment: 1 thing i can't figure out though, is how to make the main images scroll into position WHILE the gallery is closing. in other words, the gallery first closes fully and then the scrolling begins, but i would like people to see the scrolling begin immediately. i assumed that the events get fired off in the order they are received in the .js file, but i moved the code around several different ways, and either the gallery still needs to close fully first, or, something breaks entirely. this question may be too difficult to answer w/o testing, but if something comes to mind, please do let me know.

Comment: and once again, thank you for all your gracious help thus far. i have really learned a lot from you and it is very much appreciated. and hey... you never said if you are available for hire?